# Elastic Exclude fields while creating alias

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-7

I am trying to create the alias index for existing index , during this process wanted to create alias by excluding certain fields.Please let me know how to achieve.

```
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "add": {
                "index": "emp_dtl*",
                "alias": "emp_dtl_alias"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in Advance,

Siva Kumar

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [field-level security](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/field-level-security.html) and it is a commercial feature.

If a commercial license is not an option for you and if your users don't have access directly to your Elasticsearch instance, you can use [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html#source-filtering) on your alias to only return the fields they are allowed to see, but it is not recommended to pretend that it's a secure way of excluding fields from your aliased view.

[Document-level security](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/document-level-security.html) is also a commercial feature. You can exclude documents from your alias view using a [filtered alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/aliases.html#filter-alias), but it is also not recommended to pretend that it's a secure way of excluding documents.